# C# equivalent of Python code for Web Request

Tags: c#, python

I have a python `webservice` which takes contents as mentioned below:

```
a = np.expand_dims(a, axis=0)    
input_data = json.dumps({"data":  a.tolist()})
input_data = bytes(input_data, encoding='utf8')
```

I want to consume the above webservice from C# code, what could be the equivalent to call this.

I have tried this but didn't worked and I get an error mentioned below. Can anyone help ?

```
byte[] content= somevalue;
request.Content = new StringContent(content.ToList().ToString(),Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

> Error : "{\"error\": \"Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)\"}"

Consumption of the webservice in python :

```
    a = frame[startY:endY, startX:endX]
    a = cv2.resize(a, (32, 32))
    a = a.astype("float") / 255.0
    a = img_to_array(a)
    a = np.expand_dims(a, axis=0)
    input_data = json.dumps({"data":  a.tolist()})                    
    input_data = bytes(input_data, encoding='utf8')
    resp = requests.post(uri, input_data, headers=headers)
    json_data = eval(resp.json())
    j = json_data["result"][0]
```

Comment: What exectly is "a webservice"? Be detailed.

Comment: `new StringContent` expects a json string as input not the byte array. What is `somevalue` here?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya A byte array coming from an image

Comment: @KlausD. The webservice takes image as array as input , np.expand_dims converts into  array right ?

Comment: Then you can not pass it as json data to web service. You need to read the documentation of the service and understand what content type is expected by the service.

Comment: If it is a webservice, it should take a HTTP call as the input, shouldn't it? The details of the webservice are essential to consuming it.